# What happens when somebody solved mass gap problem like ultraviolet catastrophe?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, yang-mills, confinement

Just curious if somebody came along and proposed a good mathematical solution to the millennium problem but it is not intuitive at first, what happens then? this person can rigorously proof the existence of mass gap just like what happens to the ultraviolet catastrophe until we knew light is quanta? Assume the math is able to stand up to test but the interpretation becomes ambiguous instead.

Comment: I just read that many suggest that gluon confinement maybe the consequences but why can't we simply say it is a fundamental constant end of story?